# Is there a way to show cypher execution plan?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've seen a topic ([Understanding Neo4j Cypher Profile keyword and execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760627/understanding-neo4j-cypher-profile-keyword-and-execution-plan)) where *profile* keyword is mentioned.

I couldn't use it in Neo4j 2.0.0RC1 Community.

Peter wrote it's not fully implemented.

Will it ever be supported?

I mean, it could be interesting to watch the plan changes as we tune the query...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can still find the neo4j shell, where you can run the `profile` command.

Either by connecting to the running server by starting `bin/neo4j-shell`

Or by switching to the old web-ui in the "(i)" Info-menu on the left side and selecting the bottommost link "webadmin" -> `http://localhost:7474/webadmin`

Profiling information will be added to browser later on, when it is easier to read and understand.

Comment: What about current situation ? Tell me please, if profile feature was finished ?

Answer (score 18):

As of Neo4j 2.2 there are additional profiling facilities available. Some features that were only available via neo4j-shell or the REST endpoints are now available also in the Neo4j-browser, and some features are new altogether.

You can now use the `PROFILE` command with your cypher query directly in the Neo4j-browser repl to execute the query and see a visualization of the execution plan.

```
PROFILE
MATCH (n:Peter {foo: 'Paul'})
RETURN n.bar, ID(n)

-------------
n.bar   ID(n)
Mary    951
```

[image: Cypher 2.2 profile]

Additionally, you can now inspect a query plan without having to actually execute it, for instance to verify a query that would alter the database. Do so with the `EXPLAIN` command prepended to the query. See [15.2 How do I profile a query?](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/#how-do-i-profile-a-query) from the documentation.

```
EXPLAIN
MATCH (n:Peter {foo: 'Paul'})
SET n.foo = 'Mary', n.bar = 'Paul'
RETURN n.foo, ID(n)

------------------------------------------
// Nothing returned, query is not executed
```

[image: Cypher 2.2 explain]

A related new feature is also the new 'cost based' query planner, as well as the ability to force the use of either the 'cost based' or the 'rule based' query planner for all queries or for any particular query. The documentation notes that not all queries may be solvable by the 'cost based' query planner, in which case the setting will be ignored and the 'rule based' planner used. See [15.1 How are queries executed?](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/routing-decisions/)

To force the use of either query planner for all queries, set the `query.planner.version` configuration setting in `conf/neo4j.properties` (Neo4j server) or by calling the `.setConfig()` method on your `GraphDatabaseService` object (Neo4j embedded). Set it to `COST` or `RULE`, and to give the decision on which query planner to use back to Neo4j, set it to `default` (or remove the setting altogether). See [24.5 Configuration Settings](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_cypher.planner), [Starting an embedded database with configuration settings](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-setup.html#tutorials-java-embedded-setup-config).

To force the use of either query planner for a particular query, prepend your query with `CYPHER planner=cost` or `CYPHER planner=rule`. See [15.1 How are queries executed?](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/routing-decisions/)

```
CYPHER planner=cost
MATCH (n:Peter {foo: 'Paul'})
RETURN n.bar, ID(n)
```

You can `PROFILE` or `EXPLAIN` queries with either of the query planners and see any differences in how they implement your queries.

For help interpreting the execution plan, see the relevant chapter of the documentation, [16. Execution Plans](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/execution-plans/).