# How to use unwind in neo4j when adding relations using the .NET client?

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I just found the `Unwind` method on the .NET client from another SO answer. It works like a charm when adding nodes. But how do you add relations using it? I thought it would be straightfoward and wrote this:

```
client.Cypher
.Unwind(idMap, "idMap")
.Match("n1", "n2")
.Where("n1.Id=idMap.Owner")
.AndWhere("n2.Id=idMap.User")
.Create("n1-[:ONE_RELATION]->n2")
.ExecuteWithoutResults()
```

`idMap` is a list where I have a `Owner` and `User` as GUIDs. I also tried to change those to string with no luck.

The error I get is

> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
>   at
>   Neo4jClient.GraphClient.Neo4jClient.IRawGraphClient.ExecuteCypher(CypherQuery
>   query) in D:\temp\384a765\Neo4jClient\GraphClient.cs:line 1041    at
>   Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherFluentQuery.ExecuteWithoutResults() in
>   D:\temp\384a765\Neo4jClient\Cypher\CypherFluentQuery.cs:line 361    at
>   FSI_0003.connect2IdNodesList@61.Invoke(FSharpList`1 x) in
>   C:\dev\git\Sfag\src\Sfag.GraphView\Script.fsx:line 62    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.iter[T](FSharpFunc`2 f,
>   FSharpList`1 x)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ListModule.Iterate[T](FSharpFunc`2
>   action, FSharpList`1 list)    at FSI_0003.saveState(State state) in
>   C:\dev\git\Sfag\src\Sfag.GraphView\Script.fsx:line 250    at
>   .$FSI_0005.main@() in
>   C:\dev\git\Sfag\src\Sfag.GraphView\Script.fsx:line 265

which doesn't help a lot. Anyone that know what I am doing wrong here? What I can read from the docs the actual neo4j API should allow this: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-utilizing-data-structures.html, http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-unwind.html

**UPDATE**

With larger batch size I get another error:

> System.ApplicationException: Received an unexpected HTTP status when
>   executing the request.
>
> The response status was: 500 Server Error
>
> The response from Neo4j (which might include useful detail!) was:
>   at
>   Neo4jClient.GraphClient.Neo4jClient.IRawGraphClient.ExecuteCypher(CypherQuery
>   query) in D:\temp\384a765\Neo4jClient\GraphClient.cs:line 1041    at
>   Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherFluentQuery.ExecuteWithoutResults() in
>   D:\temp\384a765\Neo4jClient\Cypher\CypherFluentQuery.cs:line 361    at
>   FSI_0003.deletAllNodesOfTags@127.Invoke(String tag) in
>   C:\dev\git\Sfag\src\Sfag.GraphView\Script.fsx:line 127
>
> > at Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.mapToFreshConsTail[a,b](FSharpList`1
> >     cons, FSharpFunc`2 f, FSharpList`1 x)    at
> >     Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map[T,TResult](FSharpFunc`2
> >     mapping, FSharpList`1 x)    at
> >     Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ListModule.Map[T,TResult](FSharpFunc`2
> >     mapping, FSharpList`1 list)    at
> >     .$FSI_0003.main@() in
> >     C:\dev\git\Sfag\src\Sfag.GraphView\Script.fsx:line 142

Comment: Hi, my response to the answer here may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474497/how-to-add-edgesrelationship-neo4j-in-a-very-big-graph

Comment: That should do it, but isn't that exactly what I do?

Comment: Or does it have to be a list of anonymous objects? I'm using F# so I really want things typed :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it looks like my problem was that I didn't have an index on `Id` property. I really don't understand why that makes a difference, of course it would on speed, but crash? Keeping this question here for others to see.

I also added tags to the node match to narrow down the set of data to search for a match.

The ending F# code looks something like this:

Create index:

```
let createIndexes (client:GraphClient) = 
    client.Cypher
        .Create("INDEX ON :Enhet(Id)")
        .ExecuteWithoutResults()
```

Connect list of id pairs:

```
let connect2IdNodesList<'T  when 'T:equality> (client:GraphClient) relationType (idsToConnect: TwoIds list) = 
    let batches = List.batchesOf 10000 idsToConnect
    let startNodeType,endNodeType = getNodeTypesForRelation relationType
    let node1Str = sprintf "(n1:%s)" startNodeType
    let node2Str = sprintf "(n2:%s)" endNodeType
    batches |> List.iter (fun x -> 
                    client.Cypher
                        .Unwind(x, "idMap")
                        .Match(node1Str, node2Str)
                        .Where("n1.Id=idMap.Owner AND n2.Id=idMap.User")
                        .Create(sprintf "n1-[:%s]->n2" (relationTypeToString relationType))
                    .ExecuteWithoutResults()
            )
```

The `batchesOf` creates batches of the input just in case.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have pinged anyway the .Net Client driver author so it can look at it also.

Comment: I am pinged, have been afk for today, it is on teh radar :)