# Creating a new relationship using Python-Neo4j yields no results

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-python-driver

I am setting up a time-based graph database, around the following design principle:

[image]

I have a program which is supposed create new time-points (when relevant) in the database. I find the relevant nodes using a binary searchand then attempt to delete existing relationships (if needed) and create new relationships.

The two nodes (204452 and 203838) that I am trying to connect exist and can be retrieved using the following syntax:

```
MATCH (y1:Year)-[:CONTAINS_MONTH]->(m1:Month)-[:CONTAINS_DAY]->(d1:Day)-[:CONTAINS_TIMEPOINT]->(t1:Time)
where (y1.year='2017' AND m1.month='02' AND d1.day='28' AND t1.time='204452')
return y1, m1, d1, t1
```

The above queries yield the following subgraphs (showing that the individual queries work, right?)

[image]
[image]

However, when I try to create the connection using the following query:

```
MATCH (y1:Year {year:'2017'})-[:CONTAINS_MONTH]->(m1:Month {month:'02'})-[:CONTAINS_DAY]->(d1:Day {day:'28'})-[:CONTAINS_TIMEPOINT]->(t1:Time {time:'203838'}),
(y2:Year {year:'2017'})-[:CONTAINS_MONTH]->(m2:Month {month:'02'})-[:CONTAINS_DAY]->(d2:Day {day:'28'})-[:CONTAINS_TIMEPOINT]->(t2:Time {time:'204452'})
CREATE (t1)-[:NEXT_TIMEPOINT]->(t2)
```

Nothing happens and the Neo4j website frontend (that I was using to try and identify the issue) gives a warning about a cartesian product. I will admit that I have only recently started working with Neo4j and therefore I will mention what I think what the above query should do:

The first `MATCH` line defines and runs the first sub-query, returning the 203838 subgraph. The second `MATCH` line defines and runs the second subquery, returning the 204452 subgraph. Lastly, the `CREATE` line creates a relationship between the two time nodes acquired via the above sub-queries.

However, as there is nothing happening I assume that my understanding of the above query is wrong and I would like to know **Q1.** what it actually does and **Q2.** what would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: @BrunoPeres No, it is not. Let me upload the correct image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the warning related to the cartesian product: this happens because you are `MATCH`ing two nodes without any relations between them. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352673/why-does-neo4j-warn-this-query-builds-a-cartesian-product-between-disconnected) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751154/why-do-i-get-a-cartesian-product-warning).

To solve this warning use two `MATCH`es instead of one. I simulated your scenario here. This is the query to crate the initial dataset:

```
CREATE (y1:Year {year:'2017'})-[:CONTAINS_MONTH]->(m1:Month {month:'02'})-[:CONTAINS_DAY]->(d1:Day {day:'28'})-[:CONTAINS_TIMEPOINT]->(t1:Time {time:'203838'})
CREATE (y2:Year {year:'2017'})-[:CONTAINS_MONTH]->(m2:Month {month:'02'})-[:CONTAINS_DAY]->(d2:Day {day:'28'})-[:CONTAINS_TIMEPOINT]->(t2:Time {time:'204452'})
```

After (note the two `MATCH` statements):

```
MATCH (y1:Year {year:'2017'})-[:CONTAINS_MONTH]->(m1:Month {month:'02'})-[:CONTAINS_DAY]->(d1:Day {day:'28'})-[:CONTAINS_TIMEPOINT]->(t1:Time {time:'203838'})
MATCH (y2:Year {year:'2017'})-[:CONTAINS_MONTH]->(m2:Month {month:'02'})-[:CONTAINS_DAY]->(d2:Day {day:'28'})-[:CONTAINS_TIMEPOINT]->(t2:Time {time:'204452'})
CREATE (t1)-[:NEXT_TIMEPOINT]->(t2)
```

The result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and the links to the other questions/answers especially!

Comment: @BasJansen you are welcome! The relationship between the timepoints is being created now?

Comment: Yes it is. I am now finalizing the `if/else` structure that leads to these queries as some relationships have now been duplicated but that should be quite straight forward.

Comment: @BasJansen If you need relationships not to be duplicates you can try using a MERGE instead of CREATE. That is, change the last line to: `MERGE (t1)-[:NEXT_TIMEPOINT]->(t2)`