# Show one occurrence per node and find shortest path in neo4j using Dijkstra's Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, neo4j, cypher, dijkstra

I am working on an application which uses neo4j.
I have imported my Data Base in neo4j using CSV file and created the nodes and relations.
My Database contains 3 columns, Anumber,Bnumber and DateTime. This DB represents the calling history from `ANUMBER -> BNUMBER` with `DATETIME`

So I have created the nodes and relations by using these commands on neo4j Browser

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///2.csv" AS ROW
CREATE (a:ANUMBER {aNumber:ROW.aNumber} )
CREATE (b:BNUMBER {bNumber:ROW.bNumber} )
MERGE (a)-[:CALLED]->(b);
```

This successfully created two nodes, one relation and 2 properties keys.

**Now I am facing two issues.**

***First one*** is When I query data related to single node It creates new circle for every occurrence. I have used this query

```
MATCH p=(a:ANUMBER)-[r:CALLED]->(b:BNUMBER)
WHERE a.aNumber = "3217913664"
RETURN p
```

This results the correct response BUT it created new circle for every relation between 3217913664 and any other number. Please see the attached Image. I need to show one circle for 3217913664 and all of the edges goes out from single circle and created the required circle and edges. This image shows 23 nodes for 3217913664 BUT I only need to show one node for 3217913664 and other node as expected.
[image]

***Second one*** is I need to show the all shortest path between two numbers. Lets say

```
123 called 456,789,000,222
000 called 333,555,999
999 called 963
456 called 963
123 called 963
```

So I need to find the all shortest path between 123 and 963, which are:

```
123 -> 000 -> 999 -> 963
123 -> 456 -> 963
123 -> 963
```

Any idea how can I solve these 2 problems. I have already implemented these scenarios using [GraphStream](http://graphstream-project.org) BUT I need to implement the same use cases in neo4j using Cypher Query Language

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your first issue is related to the import script. You are creating the `a` number and `b` number for each line in your CSV. Probably this is resulting the 23 nodes with number 3217913664. To solve this replace the `CREATE` statements by `MERGE`, like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///2.csv" AS ROW
MERGE (a:ANUMBER {aNumber:ROW.aNumber} )
MERGE (b:BNUMBER {bNumber:ROW.bNumber} )
MERGE (a)-[:CALLED]->(b);
```

About the second issue: Probably you are looking for the [allShortestPath](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/all-shortest-paths-between-set-of-nodes/) function.

Comment: Yes, I want `allShortestPath`. I tried this BUT it gives no result may be due to my wrong import command. I will try your commands and see what happens for allShortestPath

Comment: I have run this query for shortest path `MATCH (a:ANUMBER {aNumber: "3217913664"}), (b:BNUMBER {bNumber: "3212862749"}),
      path = shortestpath((a)-[:CALLED*]-(b))
RETURN path`

Comment: BUT it gives me the **cartesian product warning** on first line and **The provided pattern is unbounded** on second line. Any idea how can I resolve this warning. The result is good and accurate but facong these 2 warnings

Comment: You can solve the first warning taking a look in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352673/why-does-neo4j-warn-this-query-builds-a-cartesian-product-between-disconnected). Probably a query like `MATCH (a:ANUMBER {aNumber: "3217913664"})
WITH a
MATCH (b:BNUMBER {bNumber: "3212862749"})
WITH a, b
MATCH path = shortestpath((a)-[:CALLED*]-(b))
RETURN path` will solve the first warning.

Comment: @BilalZafar, to solve the second warning you should add an upper limit to the number of node hops of your pattern. That is: the pattern `(a)-[:CALLED*]-(b)` should be something like `(a)-[:CALLED*..5]-(b)` limiting to 5 hops.