# How to optimize the following neo4j Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc

I am new to cypher and have the below query to find mistmaches between 2 source types(for example). I believe syntactically the query looks fine but it takes 1 minute to run on data set of just 1,00,000 nodes. I am not using relations still. Can someone please help in optimizing the query? Thanks.

```
MATCH (VW_OXSS41:VW_OrderXStatusSummary4{SourceTypeID: "1"}) 
WHERE apoc.date.parse(VW_OXSS41.TimeStamp,'s',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))>=apoc.date.parse("2020-02-10",'s',('yyyy-MM-dd')) AND apoc.date.parse(VW_OXSS41.TimeStamp,'s',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))<=apoc.date.parse("2020-02-16",'s',('yyyy-MM-dd'))
WITH VW_OXSS41.IdentifierValue as X
MATCH (VW_OXSS42:VW_OrderXStatusSummary4{SourceTypeID: "2"}) 
WHERE apoc.date.parse(VW_OXSS42.TimeStamp,'s',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))>=apoc.date.parse("2020-02-10",'s',('yyyy-MM-dd')) AND apoc.date.parse(VW_OXSS42.TimeStamp,'s',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))<=apoc.date.parse("2020-02-16",'s',('yyyy-MM-dd'))
WITH apoc.coll.disjunction(COLLECT(X), COLLECT(VW_OXSS42.IdentifierValue)) as XX
UNWIND (XX) as YY
```

The updated query and the error:-

```
WITH apoc.date.parse("2020-02-20",'s',('yyyy-MM-dd')) AS a, apoc.date.parse("2020-02-25",'s',('yyyy-MM-dd')) AS b
       MATCH (x:VW_OrderXStatusSummary4 {SourceTypeID: "2"}) 
       WHERE a <= apoc.date.parse(x.TimeStamp,'s',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) <= b
       WITH a, b, COLLECT(x.IdentifierValue) AS X
       MATCH (y:VW_OrderXStatusSummary4 {SourceTypeID: "1"}) 
       WHERE a <= apoc.date.parse(y.TimeStamp,'s',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) <= b
       WITH X, COLLECT(y.IdentifierValue) AS Y
       UNWIND apoc.coll.subtract(X,Y) AS XX
       MATCH (z:VW_OrderXStatusSummary4 {SourceTypeID: "2"}) 
       WHERE a <= apoc.date.parse(z.TimeStamp,'s',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) <= b
       RETURN XX AS MISMATCHES,MAX(z.TimeStamp);
Variable `a` not defined (line 10, column 7 (offset: 551))
"WHERE a <= apoc.date.parse(z.TimeStamp,'s',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) <= b"
```

Solved the above error like this:-

```
WITH apoc.date.parse("2020-02-21",'s',('yyyy-MM-dd')) AS a, apoc.date.parse("2020-02-25",'s',('yyyy-MM-dd')) AS b
MATCH (x:VW_OrderXStatusSummary4 {SourceTypeID: "2"}) 
WHERE a <= apoc.date.parse(x.TimeStamp,'s',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) <= b
WITH a, b, COLLECT(x.IdentifierValue) AS X
MATCH (y:VW_OrderXStatusSummary4 {SourceTypeID: "1"}) 
WHERE a <= apoc.date.parse(y.TimeStamp,'s',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) <= b
WITH X, COLLECT(y.IdentifierValue) AS Y
UNWIND apoc.coll.subtract(X,Y) AS XX
WITH XX, apoc.date.parse("2020-02-20",'s',('yyyy-MM-dd')) AS a, apoc.date.parse("2020-02-25",'s',('yyyy-MM-dd')) AS b
MATCH (z:VW_OrderXStatusSummary4 {SourceTypeID: "2"}) 
WHERE a <= apoc.date.parse(z.TimeStamp,'s',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) <= b
AND XX = z.IdentifierValue
RETURN XX AS MISMATCHES,MAX(z.TimeStamp);
```

With the correct expected output as:-

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| MISMATCHES          | TIMESTAMP             |
+---------------------------------------------+
| "W2002201453550218" | "2020-02-21 12:00:16" |
| "W2002201453550222" | "2020-02-21 12:00:16" |
| "W2002201453550223" | "2020-02-21 09:30:36" |
| "W2002201453550224" | "2020-02-21 12:00:16" |
| "W2002201453550226" | "2020-02-21 12:00:16" |
| "W2002201453550227" | "2020-02-21 12:00:16" |
| "W2002201453550237" | "2020-02-21 12:00:16" |
| "3011WOS002978598"  | "2020-02-21 10:00:54" |
| "3011WOS002978595"  | "2020-02-21 13:00:57" |
| "0010000000006183"  | "2020-02-21 16:00:41" |
| "W2002181111547439" | "2020-02-21 04:00:34" |
| "11"                | "2020-02-21 16:00:41" |
| "10112787861P1458"  | "2020-02-21 10:00:54" |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Wondering if there's a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to avoid making a [cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352673/why-does-neo4j-warn-this-query-builds-a-cartesian-product-between-disconnected) between the results of your two `MATCH` clauses. Let's say the two `MATCH` clauses would normally return `N` and `M` nodes, respectively, when executed in their own queries. Because your query combines those two `MATCH` clauses in the way that it does, your second `MATCH` clause is actually performing `N*M` matches (and producing `N*M` result rows).
2. You need to make sure you have created an index on `:VW_OrderXStatusSummary4(SourceTypeID)`. That will optimize the lookups performed by the `MATCH` clauses.
3. You can simplify your Cypher code to avoid duplicated function calls.

After creating the index indicated above, try this:

```
WITH apoc.date.parse("2020-02-10",'s',('yyyy-MM-dd')) AS a, apoc.date.parse("2020-02-16",'s',('yyyy-MM-dd')) AS b
MATCH (x:VW_OrderXStatusSummary4 {SourceTypeID: "1"}) 
WHERE a <= apoc.date.parse(x.TimeStamp,'s',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) <= b
WITH a, b, COLLECT(x.IdentifierValue) AS X
MATCH (y:VW_OrderXStatusSummary4 {SourceTypeID: "2"}) 
WHERE a <= apoc.date.parse(y.TimeStamp,'s',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) <= b
WITH X, COLLECT(y.IdentifierValue) AS Y
UNWIND apoc.coll.disjunction(X, Y) AS YY
...
```

Performing the `COLLECT(x.IdentifierValue)` operation in the first `WITH` clause causes it to return all the `x` nodes in a single result row (instead of `N` result rows). This allows the second `MATCH` to avoid a cartesian product issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understood what you mean. I have another problem, suppose I want to display the MAX(TimeStamp) against the YY data set which approach should I follow? I did the following but got the error:---

Comment: neo4j> WITH apoc.date.parse("2020-02-20",'s',('yyyy-MM-dd')) AS a, apoc.date.parse("2020-02-25",'s',('yyyy-MM-dd')) AS b
       MATCH (x:VW_OrderXStatusSummary4 {SourceTypeID: "2"}) 
       WHERE a <= apoc.date.parse(x.TimeStamp,'s',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) <= b
       WITH a, b, COLLECT(x.IdentifierValue) AS X
       MATCH (y:VW_OrderXStatusSummary4 {SourceTypeID: "1"}) 
       WHERE a <= apoc.date.parse(y.TimeStamp,'s',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) <=

Comment: b
       WITH X, COLLECT(y.IdentifierValue) AS Y
       UNWIND apoc.coll.subtract(X,Y) AS XX
       MATCH (z:VW_OrderXStatusSummary4 {SourceTypeID: "2"}) 
       WHERE a <= apoc.date.parse(z.TimeStamp,'s',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) <= b
       RETURN XX AS MISMATCHES,MAX(z.TimeStamp);
Variable `a` not defined (line 10, column 7 (offset: 551))
"WHERE a <= apoc.date.parse(z.TimeStamp,'s',('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) <= b"

Comment: Your last `WITH` clause did not contain `a` or `b`. But, more importantly, you are now re-introducing another cartesian product (which is totally unnecessary anyway). See the update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @cybersam, but this max_ts is actually not correct. I don't want the max TS on the complete dataset of YY, but against each record of YY, since YY property value is repeatable in the label :VW_OrderXStatusSummary4. Please see my last edit on my question.

Comment: OK, your new edit has very different logic than what was in your comment, and it seems fine. But the `MISMATCHES` value is just a single `IdentifierValue`, so it should probably be named ``MISMATCH`. I have removed my recent update to my answer.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot for the help. :)