# Neo4J: How to calculate similarity score based on number of existing paths?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a simple graph with nodes `bgc` and `protein`, where `(:bgc)-[:ENCODES]->(:protein)`. Proteins can be similar to each other, and that is represented with separate relationship, e.g. `(:protein)-[:MMSEQS_90]->(:protein)` (for 90% similarity, but can be also `MMSEQS_80`, `MMSEQS_70`, `MMSEQS_50`, etc.

For two `bgc` nodes graph can look like this:

[image: graph schema]

Paths between `bgc` nodes can be direct (sharing the exact same `protein`) or indirect (through proteins that are similar).

Now, I want to calculate similarity score between `bgc` nodes, which is defined as:

`score` = `100%  * pathsAll` / (`pathsAll + notCommon`)
Where

- `pathsAll` is total number of paths, direct and indirect (1 + 2 = 3 in the example above)
- `notCommon` are nodes not shared by any paths (3 + 2 = 5)
- `score` is similarity score: 100% * 3 / (3 + 5) = 37.5%

Score is calculated pair-wise for all `bgc` pairs, and saved as relation `(:bgc)-[:SIMILAR_TO {score: <int>})-(:bgc)`.

I have managed to solve this exact problem with query as below:

```
MATCH (bgc1:bgc)-[:ENCODING]->(p1:protein)
MATCH (bgc2:bgc)-[:ENCODING]->(p2:protein)
WHERE elementId(bgc1) < elementId(bgc2)

OPTIONAL MATCH pathIndirect = (bgc1)-[:ENCODING]->(:protein)-[:MMSEQS_90*1..5]-(:protein)<-[:ENCODING]-(bgc2)
OPTIONAL MATCH pathDirect = (bgc1)-[:ENCODING]->(:protein)<-[:ENCODING]-(bgc2)

WITH bgc1, bgc2, COUNT(DISTINCT pathIndirect) + COUNT(DISTINCT pathDirect) AS pathsAll,
              COUNT(DISTINCT p1) + COUNT(DISTINCT p2) - 2 * (COUNT(DISTINCT pathIndirect) + COUNT(DISTINCT pathDirect)) AS notCommon

WITH bgc1, bgc2, 100 * pathsAll / (pathsAll + notCommon) AS similarity_score

WITH bgc1, bgc2, similarity_score
WHERE similarity_score > 0.0  

MERGE (bgc1)-[:IS_SIMILAR {score: similarity_score}]->(bgc2)
RETURN bgc1.id AS BGC1, bgc2.id AS BGC2, similarity_score
ORDER BY similarity_score DESC, BGC1, BGC2;
```

Resulting in:

```
╒═══════╤═══════╤════════════════╕
│BGC1   │BGC2   │similarity_score│
╞═══════╪═══════╪════════════════╡
│"BGC03"│"BGC01"│83              │
├───────┼───────┼────────────────┤
│"BGC01"│"BGC02"│37              │
├───────┼───────┼────────────────┤
│"BGC03"│"BGC02"│25              │
└───────┴───────┴────────────────┘
```

This however, is immediately crashing database (out of memory) for larger number of nodes (few 1000`s), making it impossible to execute (despite reasonable memory provisioning).

I have noticed that first line can be executed instantly, but adding the second is already sufficient to cause crash (so maybe here is a first problem?):

```
// this executes instantly
MATCH rs1=(bgc1:bgc)-[:ENCODING]->(p1:protein)
RETURN rs1;
// this goes forever and crashes
MATCH rs1=(bgc1:bgc)-[:ENCODING]->(p1:protein)
MATCH rs2=(bgc2:bgc)-[:ENCODING]->(p2:protein)
RETURN rs1, rs2
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestions on why is that crashing and how to construct better query doing the same thing. Maybe I'm doing something totally wrong here - I am very new to Neo4j.

Example data:

```
MERGE (b1:bgc {id: 'BGC01'})
MERGE (b2:bgc {id: 'BGC02'})
MERGE (b3:bgc {id: 'BGC03'})
MERGE (p1:protein {id: 'PROT01'})
MERGE (p2:protein {id: 'PROT02'})
MERGE (p3a:protein {id: 'PROT03a'})
MERGE (p3b:protein {id: 'PROT03b'})
MERGE (p4a:protein {id: 'PROT04a'})
MERGE (p4b:protein {id: 'PROT04b'})
MERGE (p5:protein {id: 'PROT05'})
MERGE (p6:protein {id: 'PROT06'})
MERGE (p7:protein {id: 'PROT07'})
MERGE (p8:protein {id: 'PROT08'})
MERGE (b1)-[:ENCODING]->(p1)
MERGE (b1)-[:ENCODING]->(p2)
MERGE (b1)-[:ENCODING]->(p3a)
MERGE (b1)-[:ENCODING]->(p4a)
MERGE (b1)-[:ENCODING]->(p5)
MERGE (b1)-[:ENCODING]->(p6)
MERGE (b2)-[:ENCODING]->(p2)
MERGE (b2)-[:ENCODING]->(p3b)
MERGE (b2)-[:ENCODING]->(p4b)
MERGE (b2)-[:ENCODING]->(p7)
MERGE (b2)-[:ENCODING]->(p8)
MERGE (b3)-[:ENCODING]->(p1)
MERGE (b3)-[:ENCODING]->(p2)
MERGE (b3)-[:ENCODING]->(p5)
MERGE (b3)-[:ENCODING]->(p6)
MERGE (b3)-[:ENCODING]->(p4b)
MERGE (p3a)-[:MMSEQS_90]->(p3b)
MERGE (p4a)<-[:MMSEQS_90]-(p4b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first 2 clauses create a [cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352673/why-does-neo4j-warn-this-query-builds-a-cartesian-product-between-disconnected), which one should try to avoid:

```
MATCH (bgc1:bgc)-[:ENCODING]->(p1:protein)
MATCH (bgc2:bgc)-[:ENCODING]->(p2:protein)
```

This especially applies when the cartesian product produces mostly unwanted results. In your use case, I suspect that the vast majority of `bcg` pairs (which could be in the millions if you have thousands of encodings) would end up being dropped by your query anyway (if it ever completed).

A better approach would be to use a single `MATCH` that finds wanted paths (both direct and indirect) between `bcg` nodes. That way, you not only simplify the query but you also naturally only get wanted `bcg` pairs:

```
MATCH (bgc1:bgc)-[:ENCODING]->()-[:MMSEQS_90*0..5]-()<-[:ENCODING]-(bgc2:bgc)
WHERE elementId(bgc1) < elementId(bgc2)

WITH bgc1, bgc2,
  100 * COUNT(*) / (COUNT {(b)-[:ENCODING]->() WHERE b IN [bgc1, bgc2]} - COUNT(*)) AS similarity_score

MERGE (bgc1)-[:IS_SIMILAR {score: similarity_score}]->(bgc2)
RETURN bgc1.id AS BGC1, bgc2.id AS BGC2, similarity_score
ORDER BY similarity_score DESC, BGC1, BGC2;
```

Notes:

1. I fixed what seems like a bug in your query. In the `notCommon` calculation, I used a [COUNT subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/subqueries/count/) (introduced in neo4j 5.0) to count the number of `ENCODING` relationships for `bgc1` and `bgc2`. This produces your expected results.
2. The `0` lower bound in the variable length path pattern `0..5` allows "direct" paths to be matched.
3. If the `score` ever changed between a pair of nodes, then the `MERGE` clause above would create an additional `IS_SIMILAR` relationship. If this is a concern, you can avoid that by replacing that `MERGE` clause with:

   ```
   MERGE (bgc1)-[s:IS_SIMILAR]->(bgc2)
   SET s.score = similarity_score
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, when you do two MATCH statements in a row like that you will create a cartesian product, which is always a danger in Cypher. The result will be one row for every combination of two :ENCODING relationships in the database. If you have 1000 :ENCODING relationships you will get 1000000 rows. You limit this with WHERE elementId(bgc1) < elementId(bgc2) but you will already have created the cartesian product.

So we need to rewrite it to remove the need for that.

Secondly I get a feeling that the calculation of notCommon is incorrect. You base it on the number of paths, not the number of nodes. So it will be correct in the image you show, but not in your example data (at least if I understand you formula correctly).

Finally, you match two paths, the direct paths and the indirect paths. But in the formula you only use the sum of the two, i.e. all paths. So you don't really care what is direct and indirect. Due to this we only need one path match that covers both direct and indirect by changing 1..5 to 0..5. This also means that we can use this as the base MATCH instead of the cartesian product.

I have made a version that looks like this. Here I start first by just counting the number of proteins in the graph, to later use it to calculate notCommon:

```
MATCH (p:protein)
WITH COUNT(p) AS proteinCount

MATCH pathAll = (bgc1:bgc)-[:ENCODING]->(:protein)-[:MMSEQS_90*0..5]-(:protein)<-[:ENCODING]-(bgc2:bgc)
WHERE elementId(bgc1) < elementId(bgc2)

WITH bgc1, bgc2, SUM(SIZE([n IN nodes(pathAll) WHERE "protein" IN labels(n)])) AS commonProteins, COUNT(DISTINCT pathAll) AS pathsAll, proteinCount
WITH bgc1, bgc2, pathsAll, proteinCount-commonProteins AS notCommon

WITH bgc1, bgc2, 100 * pathsAll / (pathsAll + notCommon) AS similarity_score
WHERE similarity_score > 0.0  

MERGE (bgc1)-[:IS_SIMILAR {score: similarity_score}]->(bgc2)

RETURN bgc1.id AS BGC1, bgc2.id AS BGC2, similarity_score
ORDER BY similarity_score DESC, BGC1, BGC2
```

I don't get the same results as you get, but when I try to apply the formula manually I get the same results as my version. It might be that I have misunderstood your formula, but hopefully you can use something from my version anyway.

By the way, really nice that you provided all the MERGE statements to create your example graph. It made it a lot easier to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Well formulated question!! Kudos

In addition to the other suggestions, two other thoughts ...

1. the neo4j.conf file memory setting might be increased to avoid any RAM issues.
2. I often collect the item to be iterated and then unwind if with a call statement. This is generally more efficient in therms of code and CPUs used. In you case you may need nested calls.

   with w, collect (x) as y
   unwind y as z
   call
   {
   with z
   ... do something ...
   return answers
   }
   ... more code with w and answer..