# Query Python's iGraph as if it would be a Neo4j DB

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, igraph

I'm trying to query an `igraph` graph in python as I would do in Neo4j to find all the sets of nodes that match a given pattern. I have read through the documentation, searched for answers here, and interrogated Google with no luck.

Assuming that I have the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from igraph import Graph

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Person": ["P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P4"],
    "Object": ["O1", "O2", "O3", "O6", "O2", "O3", "O4", "O5", "O6", "O6"],
    "relation": ["LIKES"] * 10,
})
g = Graph.DataFrame(df, directed=False)
```

I'd like to run a query against `g` to return all px:Person, py:Person, ox:Object, and oy:Object such that *"px likes ox, which is also liked by py, which also likes oy AND px != py, ox != oy, (px, oy) not in df*.

Expected results would include:

```
P1, O2, P2, O4
P2, O2, P1, O1
P2, O2, P1, O6
P2, O3, P1, O1
P2, O3, P1, O6
P4, O6, P1, O1
P4, O6, P1, O2
P4, O6, P1, O3
P4, O6, P3, O5
```

but not:

```
P1, O2, P2, O3    because P1, O3 are already connected
P2, O3, P1, O2    because P2, O2 are already connected
```

In Neo4j, I'd have run something like:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:LIKES]->(o1:Object)<-[:LIKES]-(p2:Person)-[:LIKES]->(o2:Object)
WHERE p1 <> p2 AND o1 <> o2 AND NOT (p1)-[:LIKES]-(o2)
RETURN p1, o1, p2, o2
LIMIT 4 

MATCH (p1:Person)-[:LIKES]->(o1:Object)<-[:LIKES]-(p2:Person)-[:LIKES]->(o2:Object) WHERE NOT (p1)-[:LIKES]->(o2) RETURN ....
```

Notice that my input files are quite big (~75k rows) and I would like to find all the possible `(p1, o1, p2, o2)` and of course not `LIMIT 4`. I've tried to join my dataframe twice to create a result dataframe to further filter, but it gets very slow or too big to fit in memory.

I was wondering if there is a way to run such a query in `igraph`, or if I have to break it down into parts and combine the results myself. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I know you don't really care about using Cypher, but Your Cypher code creates a [cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352673/why-does-neo4j-warn-this-query-builds-a-cartesian-product-between-disconnected), which should be avoided. A better version would be: `MATCH (p1:Person)-[:LIKES]->(o1:Object)<-[:LIKES]-(p2:Person)-[:LIKES]->(o2:Object) WHERE NOT (p1)-[:LIKES]->(o2) RETURN ...`. I assume that there is at most a single `LIKES` relationship between a given person and a given object.

Comment: As an alternative, have you considered accessing an actual neo4j server using the [Python Driver](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/)? You can manipulate the DB using normal neo4j facilities (like the Browser or the driver). And you can use the driver to [transform](https://neo4j.com/docs/python-manual/current/transformers/#_transform_to_pandas_dataframe) results to a pandas Dataframe whenever you need to. You can also import data from Dataframes; [here is an article](https://towardsdatascience.com/create-a-graph-database-in-neo4j-using-python-4172d40f89c4).

Comment: Hi @cybersam, thanks for suggesting a better Cypher query (you're completely right, I wasn't thinking of cartesian product - I will update my question accordingly) and for suggesting to use Neo4j. Unfortunately I cannot deploy a Neo4j server in the remote environment I am working on...

Comment: I see you updated your Cypher, but it does not match what I provided, and therefore may be suboptimal. In a `MATCH`, you should make relationship patterns directional when possible and appropriate, to reduce effort. Also, if every `Person` node has at most 1 `LIKES` relationship to a given `Object` node, you do not need to test the `p1 <> p2 AND o1 <> o2` conditions, since a `MATCH` clause automatically filters out results that use same relationship more than once.

Comment: Duly noted! I assumed edges were bi-directional…

Comment: The directionality can be omitted when doing a `MATCH` or `MERGE`, but all relationships are stored with a specific direction. If you have a consistent direction for a relationship (say, from `Person` to `Object`), then it can be more efficient to specify the direction in a `MATCH`.