# Is it possible to reduce/optimize this query for node degrees?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given the following Cypher query that returns afferent (inbound) and efferent (outbound) connections, and the sum as the node degree:

```
START n = node(*)
RETURN n.name, length((n)-->()) AS efferent,
length((n)<--()) AS afferent,
length((n)-->()) + length((n)<--()) AS degree
```

Is it possible to reduce the query so that the two length() functions are not repeated in the summation in the degree column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve and bind the two `length` computations separately from and before returning by using `WITH`. Then you can sum those bound values while returning.

```
START n = node(*)
WITH n, length((n)-->()) AS efferent, length((n)<--()) AS afferent
RETURN n.name, efferent, afferent, efferent + afferent AS degree
```

You may want to use `MATCH (n)` instead of `START n = node(*)` if your Neo4j version is >2.0, but that's not what you're asking about so I'll assume you know what you are doing.

**EDIT**

In Neo4j 1.x `START` is how you began a query. From 2.x and on, while `START` is still around, `MATCH` is the preferred way. If you have Neo4j 2.x and don't know a particular reason why you should use `START`, then you should use `MATCH`. Here's a short explanation of why.

Your query is written to touch the entire graph. When that is the intention there is not a very big difference between `START n = node(*)` and `MATCH (n)`. The execution plans do differ, but I'm not aware that the difference is very important.

If, however, you want to perform your computations only on part of the graph, and you add to your 'starting point pattern' to that effect, then there will be significant differences. If, for example, you want to perform your computation only on nodes with the `:User` label

```
START n = node(*)
WHERE n:User
```

will still pull up all nodes, and then apply a filter to discard those that don't have the label, whereas

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n:User
```

will only pull up the nodes that have that label to begin with.

The general difference is this: `WHERE` is a dependent clause accompanying `START`, `MATCH`, `OPTIONAL MATCH` or `WITH`. When it accompanies `START` or `WITH` it does not work by modifying the operation but by filtering the results; when it accompanies `MATCH` and `OPTIONAL MATCH` it modifies (as often as it can) the operation and therefore doesn't have to filter the results. The difference is that between shouting "Everyone, if you are my child, don't go into the road" and "Kids, don't go into the road".

There are cases when `WHERE` is not pulled into the `MATCH` clause. One example is

```
MATCH n
WHERE n:Male OR n:Female
```

In this case all nodes are pulled up and then filtered, just as if we had used `START` instead of `MATCH`.

Sometimes it is easy to know which patterns in the `WHERE` clause are able to be pulled in to modify the `MATCH`. This is the case for patterns that you can move into the `MATCH` clause yourself, by simply rearranging the query. The first `MATCH` example above could also be expressed

```
MATCH (n:User)
```

There is no way, however, to do this for the `WHERE` clause in second `MATCH` example, `WHERE n:Male OR n:Female`.

That a `WHERE` pattern cannot be moved into the `MATCH` clause by reformulating the query is not a reliable indicator that the query planner is unable to make use of it in the match operation. Being a declarative language, you ultimately have to trust the query planner to wisely implement the instructions; trust, but verify.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628663/is-there-a-way-to-show-cypher-execution-plan/31534005#31534005),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760627/understanding-neo4j-cypher-profile-keyword-and-execution-plan/31534246#31534246)

One other difference between `START` and `MATCH` pertains to indexing. If you use 'legacy indexing' then you need to use `START` to access these indices. The 'new' (about two years I believe) label indices have continuously been improved for features and efficiency and we are running out of reasons to use the old indices. I think the only reason left may be full-text indexing, for which a configured legacy lucene index is still necessary. In time this feature also will be added to the label indices. Possibly, at that point, the `START` clause will be removed from Cypher altogether–but that is just the author's speculation.

Comment: No, I'm quite a neo4j noob, so all tips are appreciated.

Comment: @larsw I've added some words about `START` vs. `MATCH`.